# SyntaxError trying to access foreign key in the view function

Tags: python, django, django-templates

The function is not accepting the foreign key. It is getting a syntax error. 
This is the code of the function.
views.py

```
def projectoraccept(request, eventprojector_id):
    eventprojector = get_object_or_404(Eventprojector, pk=eventprojector_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        eventprojector.is_accept = eventprojector.is_accept+1
        eventprojector.save(update_fields=['is_accept'])

    if eventprojector.projector.sec.sec_name == 'CS_dept'
        eventprojector.projector.cs_no = eventprojector.projector.cs_no-1
        eventprojector.projector.save(update_fields=['sec'])
    elif eventprojector.projector.sec.sec_name is EC dept
        eventprojector.projector.ec_no = eventprojector.projector.ec_no-1
        eventprojector.projector.save(update_fields=['sec'])
    elif eventprojector.projector.sec.sec_name is EEE dept
        eventprojector.projector.eee_no = eventprojector.projector.eee_no-1
        eventprojector.projector.save(update_fields=['sec'])
    elif eventprojector.projector.sec.sec_name is IEEE
        eventprojector.projector.ieee_no = eventprojector.projector.ieee_no-1
        eventprojector.projector.save(update_fields=['sec'])
    elif eventprojector.projector.sec.sec_name is TCP dept
        eventprojector.projector.tcp_no = eventprojector.projector.tcp_no-1
        eventprojector.projector.save(update_fields=['sec'])
return render(request, 'event/projectordetails.html' , {'eventprojector' : eventprojector })
```

The error is

```
if eventprojector.projector.sec_name == 'CS_dept' ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What error message did you encounter?

Comment: if eventprojector.projector.sec_name == 'CS_dept'
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 3):

You don'the have the colon `:` char after the if conditions; e.g. they should be:

```
if eventprojector.projector.sec.sec_name == 'CS_dept':
```

, and so on.

The error says "SyntaxError" for a reason :)

Answer (score 1):

You must add a colon after each if and elif 
for example :

```
if eventprojector.projector.sec.sec_name == 'CS_dept' :
    # your if condition code
elif eventprojector.projector.sec.sec_name is EC dept :
   # your elif condition code
```